# Login and Registration error 3840

Tags: iphone, ios, json, ios5

I'm following along on this tutorial 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/13511/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-12 and got to the part where you implement the login and registration through Objective-c. Every time I press register or login I receive an error saying "The operation couldn't be completed. (cocoa error 3840). Also I'm not getting an error back in xcode. Help please

I just checked the mysql database and it inserts a user id but no text into username and password field

Answer (score 2):

This error can occur when the program encounters invalid JSON in the response. To determine if the JSON response is valid, use a tool like [HTTPSnoop](http://www.tuffcode.com) to examine the output of the PHP script.